# How to delete all the files with a certain extension from a folder and all of its subfolders?

Tags: folder, delete, file-format

I want to remove all the .jpg files from my Music folder in order to save room. My Music folder contains subfolders, and I would like to know if there is a command to remove all the .jpg files from all these folders regardless of their level. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way (if you are using Ubuntu Desktop):

Go to your Music folder in Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for `.jpg`.

[image]
& then delete it

---

You can also change the location and you can make your search more specific.

[image]

---

## Updated

Be More specific after searching `.jpg` Clicking on green button `Select File type Picture` & then remove `jpg` from search only `.` dot & then `reload` as shown in pic below

> What it does it will search Picture file like `.jpg .png .gif` & all other file which are in `Picture Format`

[image]

Comment: even better :) :)

Answer (score 99):

A quick and clean solution for the command line would be

```
cd <dir>
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg -delete
```

- `.` tells to start searching in the current folder.
- `-type f` tells find only to look for files.
- `-iname` makes the search case insensitive.
- `-delete` tells find to delete/remove all files found.

**CAUTION! I recommend running the command without `-delete` first to get a list of the files that will be removed when `-delete` is included in the command. This way a small typo won't delete anything you didn't intend to.**

For more information on how to use `find` and what it can do see `man find`

Note that `find` will not produce any output when `-delete` is used.

Regarding the comment on multiple extensions

`find . -type f \( -name \*jpg -o -name \*png \) -delete`

- `( .. )` Group expression. Needs to be escaped from the shell, hence `\( .. \)` in the example
- `-o` logical or

So the above example will match any file which has either `jpg` or `png` at the end of it's name. More extensions can be added in the same way. Just make sure to remember `-o` between every `-name` statement, if `-o` is not specified `find` will default to `-a` (and) which won't work since a file can't end in both `jpg` and `png` at the same time.

Comment: How about I want to delete multiple types of extensions?

Comment: CAUTION: This will delete images inside SUBFOLDERS as well. Google brought me here to my misfortune. Do `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \*.jpg -delete` if you want to protect the subfolders.

Comment: The question states that the OP is looking for deleting all files including subfolders.

Comment: Do not run this in the home directory, it would go inside directories starting with **.** and delete things

Answer (score 12):

This should do it

```
sudo rm -rf -d ~/Music/*.JPG
```

which will remove all .JPG files within the Music folder.

Comment: This will not remove files from subfolders …

Comment: This is a good command when you don't want to clean subfolders, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Bash's `shopt -s globstar` can be useful here for recursive globbing:

```
bash-4.3$ tree
.
├── 10.jpg
└── subfolder
    ├── 5.jpg
    └── another_subfolder
        └── 15.jpg

2 directories, 3 files
bash-4.3$ shopt -s globstar
bash-4.3$ rm ./**/*.jpg
bash-4.3$ tree
.
└── subfolder
    └── another_subfolder
```