# Delete all files with certain name in entire directory

Tags: 12.04, directory, delete, hidden-files

I have a directory that I want to delete all the .svn folders in all of its subdirectories. Is there a command that can do this without me having to go through each individual subdirectory and delete them that way? I tried doing it through nautilus as suggested here [How to delete all the files with a certain extension from a folder and all of its subfolders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104831/how-to-delete-all-the-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-a-folder-and-all-of-it)

But when I search, it does not show any hidden folders, even though I have that option enabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all such directories:

```
find -name .svn -type d
```

If you are sure, delete all of them:

```
find -name .svn -type d -delete
```

Comment: Sorry for the edit. It's my bad - have forgotten '.svn' is the exact name. Can't find a way to cancel it - please ignore.